# Receiving Python unindent errors on conditionals I think looks correctly indented

Tags: python

Below is some code: I want to run the final for loop and I receive this asinine unindent error upon compilation. I know python's indentation rules are pretty straight forward and more or less represent {} in C. WHY am I getting  "

```
File "script.py", line 153
    if ("&" in each):
                    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

when my code looks fine?

```
daily_sales = \
"""Edith Mcbride   ;,;$1.21   ;,;   white ;,; 
09/15/17   ,Herbert Tran   ;,;   $7.29;,; 
white&blue;,;   09/15/17 ,Paul Clarke ;,;$12.52 
;,;   white&blue ;,; 09/15/17 ,Lucille Caldwell   
;,;   $5.13   ;,; white   ;,; 09/15/17,
Eduardo George   ;,;$20.39;,; white&yellow 
;,;09/15/17   ,   Danny Mclaughlin;,;$30.82;,;   
purple ;,;09/15/17 ,Stacy Vargas;,; $1.85   ;,; 
purple&yellow ;,;09/15/17,   Shaun Brock;,; 
$17.98;,;purple&yellow ;,; 09/15/17 , 
Erick Harper ;,;$17.41;,; blue ;,; 09/15/17, 
Michelle Howell ;,;$28.59;,; blue;,;   09/15/17   , 
Carroll Boyd;,; $14.51;,;   purple&blue   ;,;   
09/15/17   , Teresa Carter   ;,; $19.64 ;,; 
white;,;09/15/17   ,   Jacob Kennedy ;,; $11.40   
;,; white&red   ;,; 09/15/17, Craig Chambers;,; 
$8.79 ;,; white&blue&red   ;,;09/15/17   , Peggy Bell;,; $8.65 ;,;blue   ;,; 09/15/17,   Kenneth Cunningham ;,;   $10.53;,;   green&blue   ;,; 
09/15/17   ,   Marvin Morgan;,;   $16.49;,; 
green&blue&red   ;,;   09/15/17 ,Marjorie Russell 
;,; $6.55 ;,;   green&blue&red;,;   09/15/17 ,
Israel Cummings;,;   $11.86   ;,;black;,;  
09/15/17,   June Doyle   ;,;   $22.29 ;,;  
black&yellow ;,;09/15/17 , Jaime Buchanan   ;,;   
$8.35;,;   white&black&yellow   ;,;   09/15/17,   
Rhonda Farmer;,;$2.91 ;,;   white&black&yellow   
;,;09/15/17, Darren Mckenzie ;,;$22.94;,;green 
;,;09/15/17,Rufus Malone;,;$4.70   ;,; green&yellow 
;,; 09/15/17   ,Hubert Miles;,;   $3.59   
;,;green&yellow&blue;,;   09/15/17   , Joseph Bridges  ;,;$5.66   ;,; green&yellow&purple&blue 
;,;   09/15/17 , Sergio Murphy   ;,;$17.51   ;,;   
black   ;,;   09/15/17 , Audrey Ferguson ;,; 
$5.54;,;black&blue   ;,;09/15/17 ,Edna Williams ;,; 
$17.13;,; black&blue;,;   09/15/17,   Randy Fleming;,;   $21.13 ;,;black ;,;09/15/17 ,Elisa Hart;,; $0.35   ;,; black&purple;,;   09/15/17   ,
Ernesto Hunt ;,; $13.91   ;,;   black&purple ;,;   
09/15/17,   Shannon Chavez   ;,;$19.26   ;,; 
yellow;,; 09/15/17   , Sammy Cain;,; $5.45;,;   
yellow&red ;,;09/15/17 ,   Steven Reeves ;,;$5.50   
;,;   yellow;,;   09/15/17, Ruben Jones   ;,; 
$14.56 ;,;   yellow&blue;,;09/15/17 , Essie Hansen;,;   $7.33   ;,;   yellow&blue&red
;,; 09/15/17   ,   Rene Hardy   ;,; $20.22   ;,; 
black ;,;   09/15/17 ,   Lucy Snyder   ;,; $8.67   
;,;black&red  ;,; 09/15/17 ,Dallas Obrien ;,;   
$8.31;,;   black&red ;,;   09/15/17,   Stacey Payne 
;,;   $15.70   ;,;   white&black&red ;,;09/15/17   
,   Tanya Cox   ;,;   $6.74   ;,;yellow   ;,; 
09/15/17 , Melody Moran ;,;   $30.84   
;,;yellow&black;,;   09/15/17 , Louise Becker   ;,; 
$12.31 ;,; green&yellow&black;,;   09/15/17 ,
Ryan Webster;,;$2.94 ;,; yellow ;,; 09/15/17 
,Justin Blake ;,; $22.46   ;,;white&yellow ;,;   
09/15/17,   Beverly Baldwin ;,;   $6.60;,;   
white&yellow&black ;,;09/15/17   ,   Dale Brady   
;,;   $6.27 ;,; yellow   ;,;09/15/17 ,Guadalupe Potter ;,;$21.12   ;,; yellow;,; 09/15/17   , 
Desiree Butler ;,;$2.10   ;,;white;,; 09/15/17  
,Sonja Barnett ;,; $14.22 ;,;white&black;,;   
09/15/17, Angelica Garza;,;$11.60;,;white&black   
;,;   09/15/17   ,   Jamie Welch   ;,; $25.27   ;,; 
white&black&red ;,;09/15/17   ,   Rex Hudson   
;,;$8.26;,;   purple;,; 09/15/17 ,   Nadine Gibbs 
;,;   $30.80 ;,;   purple&yellow   ;,; 09/15/17   , 
Hannah Pratt;,;   $22.61   ;,;   purple&yellow   
;,;09/15/17,Gayle Richards;,;$22.19 ;,; 
green&purple&yellow ;,;09/15/17   ,Stanley Holland 
;,; $7.47   ;,; red ;,; 09/15/17 , Anna Dean;,;$5.49 ;,; yellow&red ;,;   09/15/17   ,
Terrance Saunders ;,;   $23.70  ;,;green&yellow&red 
;,; 09/15/17 ,   Brandi Zimmerman ;,; $26.66 ;,; 
red   ;,;09/15/17 ,Guadalupe Freeman ;,; $25.95;,; 
green&red ;,;   09/15/17   ,Irving Patterson 
;,;$19.55 ;,; green&white&red ;,;   09/15/17 ,Karl Ross;,;   $15.68;,;   white ;,;   09/15/17 , Brandy Cortez ;,;$23.57;,;   white&red   ;,;09/15/17, 
Mamie Riley   ;,;$29.32;,; purple;,;09/15/17 ,Mike Thornton   ;,; $26.44 ;,;   purple   ;,; 09/15/17, 
Jamie Vaughn   ;,; $17.24;,;green ;,; 09/15/17   , 
Noah Day ;,;   $8.49   ;,;green   ;,;09/15/17   
,Josephine Keller ;,;$13.10 ;,;green;,;   09/15/17 ,   Tracey Wolfe;,;$20.39 ;,; red   ;,; 09/15/17 ,
Ignacio Parks;,;$14.70   ;,; white&red ;,;09/15/17 
, Beatrice Newman ;,;$22.45   ;,;white&purple&red 
;,;   09/15/17, Andre Norris   ;,;   $28.46   ;,;   
red;,;   09/15/17 ,   Albert Lewis ;,; $23.89;,;   
black&red;,; 09/15/17,   Javier Bailey   ;,;   
$24.49   ;,; black&red ;,; 09/15/17   , Everett Lyons ;,;$1.81;,;   black&red ;,; 09/15/17 ,   
Abraham Maxwell;,; $6.81   ;,;green;,;   09/15/17   
,   Traci Craig ;,;$0.65;,; green&yellow;,; 
09/15/17 , Jeffrey Jenkins   ;,;$26.45;,; 
green&yellow&blue   ;,;   09/15/17,   Merle Wilson 
;,;   $7.69 ;,; purple;,; 09/15/17,Janis Franklin   
;,;$8.74   ;,; purple&black   ;,;09/15/17 ,  
Leonard Guerrero ;,;   $1.86   ;,;yellow  
;,;09/15/17,Lana Sanchez;,;$14.75   ;,; yellow;,;   
09/15/17   ,Donna Ball ;,; $28.10  ;,; 
yellow&blue;,;   09/15/17   , Terrell Barber   ;,; 
$9.91   ;,; green ;,;09/15/17   ,Jody Flores;,; 
$16.34 ;,; green ;,;   09/15/17,   Daryl Herrera 
;,;$27.57;,; white;,;   09/15/17   , Miguel Mcguire;,;$5.25;,; white&blue   ;,;   09/15/17 ,   
Rogelio Gonzalez;,; $9.51;,;   white&black&blue   
;,;   09/15/17   ,   Lora Hammond ;,;$20.56 ;,; 
green;,;   09/15/17,Owen Ward;,; $21.64   ;,;   
green&yellow;,;09/15/17,Malcolm Morales ;,;   
$24.99   ;,;   green&yellow&black;,; 09/15/17 ,   
Eric Mcdaniel ;,;$29.70;,; green ;,; 09/15/17 
,Madeline Estrada;,;   $15.52;,;green;,;   09/15/17 
, Leticia Manning;,;$15.70 ;,; green&purple;,; 
09/15/17 ,   Mario Wallace ;,; $12.36 ;,;green ;,; 
09/15/17,Lewis Glover;,;   $13.66   ;,;   
green&white;,;09/15/17,   Gail Phelps   ;,;$30.52   
;,; green&white&blue   ;,; 09/15/17 , Myrtle Morris 
;,;   $22.66   ;,; green&white&blue;,;09/15/17"""

daily_sales_replaced = daily_sales.replace(";,;","->")
daily_transactions = daily_sales_replaced.split(",")
daily_transactions_split = []
transactions_clean = []
customers = []
sales = []
thread_sold = []
thread_sold_split = []

print(daily_transactions)

for i in daily_transactions:
  for transaction in daily_transactions:
    #transaction.split("->")
    daily_transactions_split.append(transaction.split("->"))
print(daily_transactions_split)

for transaction in daily_transactions_split:
  print(transaction)
  temp_list = []
  for x in transaction:
    print(x.split())
    temp_list.append(x.split())
  transactions_clean.append(temp_list)
print(transactions_clean)

for i in transactions_clean:
  customers.append(i[0])
  sales.append(i[1])
  thread_sold.append(i[2])
print(customers)
print(sales)
print(thread_sold)

total_sales = 0
for i in sales:
  for each in i:
    total_sales += float(each.strip("$"))
print(total_sales)

print(thread_sold)

for i in thread_sold:
  for each in i:
    print(each)
    if ("&" in each):
        each.split("&")
        thread_sold_split.append(each.split("&"))
    else:
        thread_sold_split.append(each)
```

Comment: Try selecting the whole code block in which ever line the indentation error is coming. And press SHIFT + TAB , then again press TAB. Sometimes due to some unnecessary spaces create indentation issues.

Comment: You have a mix of tabs and spaces in this code. Just use spaces.

Comment: For your case, select lines starting from "for each in i:" to end of the code and press SHIFT+TAB and then press TAB. This might resolve your issue.

Comment: The error doesn't reproduce with a cut-and-paste.  This suggests that the problem is white space only.  It's quite possible that you've mixed tabs and spaces in your indentation.

Comment: @SurajitMitra: Your advice is almost certainly specific to a particular IDE. Python code can be written in any text editor, so you probably shouldn't make that sort of assumption. Or at least, you should say what IDE your advice is for.

Comment: It had something to do with the spaces and tabs. I will from now on use 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure what's going on in your code because StackOverflow automatically replaces tabs with spaces in code blocks.

However, as others have suggested, it is likely you have a mix of tab characters and spaces in your code. We say this because we have made the same mistake ourselves many times in the past. Sometimes many times in the same 10 minutes.

Usually it is suggested to always use 4 spaces per indent. I prefer a little less (2 or 3) but I have forced myself to go with the rest of society and adhere to the [PEP 8 Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) that says 4.

Most code editors can be configured to replace a typed tab character with a programmable number of spaces (usually defaulting to 4). Also, many code editors have a command to replace all with spaces for in a file. I use this one a lot. I use Geany a lot as a code editor, but every time I do a new install on a different machine, I have to remember to 
set the option to use ONLY spaces for indentation.